# Proper CSS syntax

Tags: css, css-selectors

When writing and referencing elements in my Stylesheets, is

```css
ul#display-inline-block-example li
```

And

```css
#display-inline-block-example ul li
```

The same thing? If not what is wrong with one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they're not.

The first is applying styles to an `li`, which is nested inside a `ul` with id `display-inline-block-example`

The second is applying styles to an `li`, which is nested inside a `ul`, which is nested inside any element type with the id `display-inline-block-example`

Answer (score 1):

No. The first:

```
ul#display-inline-block-example li
```

will target list items within an unordered-list with the `id` `display-inline-block-example`.

The second:

```
#display-inline-block-example ul li
```

will target list items within an unordered-list whose container (could be anything) has the `id` `display-inline-block-example`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second selector says that `li` is a successor of some `ul` which has `#display-inline-block-example` element as an ancestor. This is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

1.ul#display-inline-block-example li

2.#display-inline-block-example ul li

the first one will target li inside  with id="#display-inline-block-example" like

ul id="display-inline-block-example"
 li /li - 1.first selector will target this element
/ul

the second one will target all ul li inside element with the id selector "#display-inline-block-example"

e.g:

div id="display-inline-block-example"
       ul li /li /ul -
       ul  li  /li /ul - these will get affected if you write styles using this "#display-inline-block-example ul li " selector
   /div